# Вкладки Tabs Material Design - как добавить иконки

Tags: java, android

Привет. Я новичок. Пробую рекомендованный Гуглом дизайн.

Получилось написать вкладки с **текстом**. И всё что мне теперь осталось - поменять текст на **иконки**.

*tool_bar.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
android:elevation="2dp"
android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 />
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

<startandroid.ru.daytwo.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence Titles[]={"Вкладка 1","Вкладка 2", "Вкладка 3"};
int Numboftabs = 3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);

    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
}

public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);
    image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
    SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return sb;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

*ViewPagerAdapter.java*

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

CharSequence Titles[];
int NumbOfTabs;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
    super(fm);
    this.Titles = mTitles;
    this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    if(position == 0)
    {
        Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
        return tab1;
    }
    else
    {
        Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
        return tab2;
    }
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return Titles[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NumbOfTabs;
}
}
```

Как лучше всего это сделать? Если надо, могу скинуть *SlidingTabLayout.java* и *SlidingTabStrip.java*

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего пользоваться новым [`TabLayout`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) из `design` либы от гугла. Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30914445/3212712), добавление иконок к табам очень просто:

```
//связываем табы с pager-ом
mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
//пробегаемся по табам и ставим им иконки
for (int i = 0; i < mTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
  mTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);
}
```